# Deleting MySQL LocalHost Server in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I set up a MySQL LocalHost server on my computer a few weeks ago.  I've been testing some code on the server, but now I'd like to delete it.  When I open up my MySQL Workbench Workspace view, the server LocalHost pops up under the "Server Administration" and "Open Connection to Start Querying" sections.  I right click on the LocalHost listings under both sections and delete them.  Unfortunately, when I restart MySQL Workbench, the LocalHost instance I deleted from the previous session pops back up.  How do I permanently get rid of the LocalHost instance in my MySQL Workbench Workspace view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench will load the localhost server instance by default.  As of Workbench 5.2.40 there does not seem to be a way to disable this action.

If you truly do not wish to see the server in Workbench then I am assuming you are no longer using the localhost server as you said it was for testing anyways.  If you uninstall the server from your machine then it will no longer show up in Workbench.  However, given the small footprint of two list items (for the server and the connection) it hardly seems worth getting bothered over IMO.

Answer (score 1):

As of Workbench 6, the local connections are no longer automatically added after a restart. However, to add them, right-click on the Workbench Home screen and select "Rescan for Local MySQL Connections" from the context-menu.